# Validate html table cell and stop navigation

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to the SO as well as new to the web development. I have a dynamic HTML table. I want to validate the one of the input type cell and stop the navigation if the validation fails. below code doesn't work. please help me, thank you!

**HTML:**

```
<table id="tblpay">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CUST ID</th>
            <th>Balance Due </th>
            <th>Payment Amt </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% while (rs.next()) { %>               
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=rs.getString("cust_id")%>
            </td>
            <td class="right" id="amount_due">
                <%=rs.getString("amount_due")%>
            </td >
            <td class="right" id="payamt">
                <div id="edit1">
                    <input type="number" id="payinput" class="payc"
                     onchange="return validatedata(this); "  value = <%=rs.getString("amount_due")%> > </input>
                </div>
            </td>                    
        </tr>               
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function validatedata(e){
    if (!isNaN(parseFloat(e.value)) && isFinite(e.value)){
        return true;
    }
    else {               
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal and usable code sample which reproduce the problem you're having, without the extra code that we (and the rest of the internet) doesn't have, like the js templating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
 onchange="return validatedata(this); "
```

to

```
 onkeypress="return validatedata(this); "
```

And :

```
 function validatedata(evt){

var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31
&& (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

return true;
```

}

http://jsbin.com/nelujedozi/2/edit

Comment: SO provides code snippet that can directly be embedded in answers.

Comment: Thank You, Royi Namir. it worked. it allows user only to enter numeric instead allow them to enter anything and then validate and stop.